# Is Aham Brahmasmi the embodiment principle of seeing the veda by the Maharshis?

Tags: puranas, bhagavad-gita, advaita, smriti, sruti

Since source of  divine knowledge is impersonal Brahman, through the Maharshi's, which principle, statement or shloka from Vedas, Puranas and Bhagavatam elucidates this, or supports it? All ultimate truths can arise again and again from truth itself. If it is already answered by someone may he link it with a concise core explanation. Would Aham Brahmasmi be helpful in this thesis,?

Comment: Would this have any connection, that truth can arise anywhere?      सहस्रपरमा देवी शतमूला शताङ्कुरा। 
सर्वँहरतु मे पापं दूर्वा दुःस्वप्ननाशिनी॥ ३४॥ काण्डात् काण्डात् प्ररोहन्ती परुषः परुषः परि। एवा नो दूर्वे प्रतनु सहस्रेण शतेन च॥ ३५॥ 
या शतेन प्रतनोषि सहस्रेण विरोहसि।
तस्यास्ते देवीष्टके विधेम हविषा वयम् ॥ ३६॥